# Macro Function assign output to Macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

**I am trying to pass the value of this macro to** `output`  **macro variable**

```
%Macro Get_expression(tablename,code);
    proc sql;
        select Sql_expression
        From &tablename.
        where Cod = &code.;
    quit;
run;
%MEND Get_data;

*Print the macro

%let output=%Get_expression(dtvault.parameterjobs,'DO_M_R_C');
%put &output;
```

**but I'm having this error**

```
NOTE: Writing TAGSETS.SASREPORT13(EGSR) Body file: EGSR
24         
25         GOPTIONS ACCESSIBLE;
26         %Macro Get_expression(tablename,code);
27             proc sql;
28              select Sql_expression
29              From &tablename.
30              where Cod = &code.;
31          quit;
32         run;
33         %MEND Get_data;
WARNING: Extraneous text on %MEND statement ignored for macro definition GET_EXPRESSION.
34         
35         *Calling a Macro program;
36         %let output=%Get_expression(dtvault.parameterjobs,'DO_M_R_C');
NOTE: Line generated by the invoked macro "GET_EXPRESSION".
36         proc sql;   select Sql_expression   From &tablename.   where Cod = &code.;  quit; run;
                       ______
                       180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.


37         %put &output;
```

What am I doing wrong?

If a run only this

```
%Get_expression(dtvault.parameterjobs,'DO_M_R_C');
```

**the tab result apears with query result correct**

Thanks, G.O

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for `select into` statement. Here is an example:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select "'" || strip(name) || "'" /*format=*/ into :name_list separated by ", "
    from sashelp.class;
quit;
%put &name_list.;
```

Remember that SAS macro variables are always text. That's why formatting matters.

Comment: Thanks  @Petr.   I'll analyze it bette

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues.

1. The name at the %MEND needs to match the macro name (get_expression vs get_data)
2. You don't actually create any output or macro variable. The output goes to the ODS window. You can modify your code by doing a select into : to create macro variable but you need to make sure you know the name and assign the correct scope (local/global). But you're trying to use a macro as a function - which it's not. PROC FCMP is designed to build functions, this looks a lot like a lookup table instead.

This is how I would do this, where it's looking up the weight of a person in the SASHELP.CLASS data set.

```
%macro get_data(tablename=, name=, output_name=);
     data _null_;
          set &tablename.;
          where name= &name. ;
          call symputx("&output_name.", weight, 'g');
     run;
%mend;

%get_data(tablename=sashelp.class, name='Alfred', output_name=myVar);
%put &myVar;
```

Comment: Thanks @Reeza. I'll analyze it better.

Answer (score 0):

The macro just generates text.  In your case the beginning of the text that it generates is

```
proc sql; select Sql_expression
```

So when you use it inside of another statement, like your `%LET` statement

```
%let output=%Get_expression(dtvault.parameterjobs,'DO_M_R_C');
```

the macro call gets replaced by the generated text.  So you end up with code like this that SAS will now need to evaluate.

```
%let output=proc sql; select Sql_expression
```

The first semi-colon marks the end of the `%LET` statement. So the macro variable OUTPUT has the value `proc sql`. And the `SELECT` statement is invalid because you never actually started PROC SQL.